# Confused with hosting types

Tags: vps, cloud

Hey guys am going to buy a linux vps server.But i have some doubts regarding about this.

I know cloud server and vps server are very different from each other ..i have heard `digital ocean` provides vps cloud hosting service ..Actually is vps cloud hosting same as cloud hosting ??..or vps cloud hosting is a type of vps hosting..

i would like to know if vps cloud hosting and cloud hosting is same or different ...i have searched about this but  i didn get proper idea.

Those who guys have any good knowledge about this please post as an answer or as a comment.Any help would be appreciated ..Thanx

Answer (score 1):

*"cloud"* is a marketing buzzword, while *"vps"* more or less refers to the technical specification of an always-on virtual instance of an operating system (or a container / compartment thereof) with a varying percentage of dedicated and shared resources (CPU time, memory, networking bandwidth, storage).

So the terms `cloud` and `vps` are certainly not *"the same"* as in *"synonymous"*, but you obviously could compare the technical specifications and the price lists of differnt offerings marketed under various names and find that they *might* be similar.